# Rotational Linear Operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it correct to say that a linear operator $T:V\to V$, $dim V=n$ is a rotational operator if there is a base $B$ of $V$ such that the matrix of $T$ in base $B$, saying $R$ satisfies:

$R\cdot {R^T}=I_n$ and $\det{R}=1$, where $R^T$ denotes the transpose of $R$.

??

Comment: "the matrix of T is base B, saying R" Do you mean the matrix of T is R under the base B?

Comment: in base B. Sorry...

Comment: In fact, $RR^T=I_n$ (personally I think $R^T$ is preferable to $^t R$) can only yield that $R$ is orthogonal. $T$ can either be a **reflective** or a **rotational** transformation, or even combination of the two. To make sure that $T$ is rotational, an additional condition is needed : $|T|=1$. If $T$ is reflective, then $|T|$ will be otherwise, i.e. $-1$.

Comment: I have edited my post.

Comment: Oh. Then it's all we need. the answer should be yes now. Since a rotational transformation (at least in my textbook) is itself define as an orthogonal transformation whose determinant is $1$.

Comment: I asked that because I saw that these linear transformation are defined only on euclidian spaces, and I wonder if this definition could be extended to arbitrary linear spaces...

Comment: @Bodgan I confess that I've **always** been thinking that every linear space is euclidean...

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to formulate your question in another way.

Simply given a vector space $V$, it makes no "sense" to say the word "rotation", since we do not even have a device to measure angles. To do this we need an inner product $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ on $V$. Abstractly this is just a positive definite symmetric bilinear form.

Furthermore a "rotation" should preserve orientation, so we only consider operators with determinant $1$.

Then a linear operator is called a rotation if it has determinant $1$ and preserves the inner product, i.e. the geometric structure is preserved:

$\langle Av,Aw \rangle = \langle v,w\rangle$ for all $v,w\in V$

Pick a basis of $V$ then the inner product can be written as $\langle v, w \rangle = v^TGw$ with $G$ being the gram matrix, and linear operators that preserves it are exactly those that satisfies $A^TGA=G$.

In the case of the standard inner product in the standard basis, $G=I_n$ and we have your identity immediately. It is also interesting to note that it in fact does not depend on the choice of basis.

As an additional comment, there are similar notions for a complex vector space with a hermitian form. We could also extend our scope to bilinear forms that are not positive definite, for example the bilinear form with signature (3,1) on $\mathbb{R}^4$. It is positive definite in $3$ directions and negative definite in the $4^{th}$ direction. This is a standard model in special relativity, with the positive definite directions called space like and the negative definite direction time like. Then the isometries of such a space is exactly the group of Lorentz transformations.